# HTML tables with python beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, scrapy

I have a HTML table which looks like this :

```
<table border=0 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2 class=form>
<tr class=form><td class=formlabel>Heating Coils in Bunker Tanks</td><td class=form>N</td></tr>
<tr class=forma><td class=formlabel>Heating Coils in Cargo Tanks</td><td class=form>U</td></tr>
<tr class=form><td class=formlabel>Manifold Type</td><td class=form>N</td></tr>
<tr class=forma><td class=formlabel>No. Holds</td><td class=form>5</td></tr>
<tr class=form><td class=formlabel>No. Centreline Hatches</td><td class=form>5</td></tr>
<tr class=forma><td class=formlabel>Lifting Gear</td><td class=form>Yes</td></tr>
<tr class=form><td class=formlabel>Gear</td><td class=form>4 Crane (30.5t SWL)</td></tr>
<tr class=forma><td class=formlabel>Alteration</td><td class=form>Unknown</td></tr>
</table>
```

I am using Beautiful soup to extract specific data which comes as a response from a scrapy spider

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body_as_unicode())
table= soup.find('table', {'class': 'form'})
# psusedo code find manifold type and number of Holds
```

How do i go about doing this.Do note that the ordering of the values might change but the form label always remains the same ? How do i search using a specific form label ?

## Edit:

```
<tr class=forma><td class=formlabel>Fleet Manager (Operator)</td><td class=form><a href="oBasic.asp?LRNumber=9442964&Action=Display&LRCompanyNumber=40916">ESSAR SHIPPING LTD</a></td></tr>
```

this particular case scenario does not work with the following sibling search ? How to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `td` element [by text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) and get the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
table.find('td', text='Manifold Type').next_sibling.text
```

As a side note, why do you need to use `BeautifulSoup` inside a Scrapy spider? `Scrapy` itself is pretty powerful in terms of HTML parsing, locating elements:

```
response.xpath('//table[@class="form"]//td[.="Manifold Type"]/following-sibling::td/text()')
```

Demo from the [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
In [1]: response.xpath('//table[@class="form"]//td[.="Manifold Type"]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract()
Out[1]: [u'N']
```

Comment: @Alecxe..the scrapy xpath solution worked like a charm..however..see edit..i have a table in which the next sibling is a href..In those scenarios i get a blank result..how can i get the text in that case in this case essar shipping..

Comment: @Amistad good, `//table[@class="form"]//td[.="Manifold Type"]/following-sibling::td/a/text()` should do the trick.